# Re-arranging a list into columns

Tags: performance, vba, excel

In short, what this script aims to do is take the following data:

```
1
Alpha
Beta
Delta
2
Beta
Echo
Foxtrot
Kilo
3 
Alpha
Kilo
4 
Beta
Echo
Kilo
Zulu
```

And re-arrange like this:

```
1       2        3      4
Alpha   Beta     Alpha  Beta
Beta    Echo     Kilo   Echo
Delta   Foxtrot         Kilo
        Kilo            Zulu
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
      Private Sub PrepareLibrary()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Range 
Dim x As Long
Dim Library As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set Library = Sheets("Library")
i = 1
x = 0
LastRow = Library.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

Do While i <= LastRow
Set Rng = Library.Range("A" & i)
Set n = Library.Range("A1")

If IsNumeric(Rng) = True Then  
x = x + 1 
Rng.Copy
n.Offset(0, x).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
i = i + 1
ElseIf IsNumeric(Rng) = False Then
Rng.Copy
n.Offset(1, x).Insert Shift:=xlDown
i = i + 1
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 0 Then
i = i + 1

End If
Loop 
End Sub
```

Essentially, this runs through Column A one at time, copying each cell across individually, pasting into a new row whenever it comes across a number. It works well on small databases, but when expanding out to over 20,000 rows of data, I get a "not enough resources" message. Willing to attempt an entirely different approach if it seems possible. I'm new to VBA, so that may explain why this code is quite inefficient.

Comment: Is This a homework assignment? see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023285/in-excel-i-want-to-search-for-individual-words-across-a-worksheet-and-pull-an)

Comment: Quick tip as I may not have time to write a review for a while: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` are also 2 good ones to throw in for speed improvements.

Comment: Great, I'll try them. And no, g leachman, it is not. I thought this would be a more suitable place to post, as the code is already working well.

Comment: Are the numbers sequential and ordinal (e.g. *1, 2, 3, ... 998, 999*)? If they are, a lot of code that would otherwise be necessary to determine the scope of the results could be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naming tells me nothing and doesn't follow [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx).

```
Dim i - this is a counter? why not rowNumber
Dim n - this is also a counter? why not labelNumber
Dim x - is this a counter? why not nextRowNumber
Dim Library should be library
Dim LastRow should be lastRow
```

With `library` in fact Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (F4) and the `(Name)` field can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mySheet")` and instead just use `mySheet`.

A good way to speed up your macro is to use `Application.Screenupdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Just be sure to return them to `True` and `xlAutomatic` and `True` before exiting the sub.

---

Additionally, you're doing everything on the sheet, which is slow by nature. Even just reading into an array *should* be quicker -

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub PrepareLibrary()
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim resultsIndex As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As Long
    currentColumn = 0
    lastRow = Library.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim results(1 To lastRow)
    results = Library.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

    For resultsIndex = 1 To lastRow
        If IsNumeric(results(resultsIndex, 1)) Then
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, currentColumn) = results(resultsIndex, 1)
            currentRow = 2
        Else:
        Sheet2.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) = results(resultsIndex, 1)
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        End If
     Next
     Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub
```

That's not a very good example of using the array to the maximum benefit, but it's something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm widely self-taught, so I was not aware of Standard Naming Conventions until now. Integers i and n are indeed counters, but n is a range.

Comment: Sure, take a look at my addition and see if it is speedier

Comment: Also, don't worry - I'm self-taught as well and if you went back through my coding on superuser, the older stuff would embarrass me. Even some of my current stuff isn't that great.

Comment: Awesome, this definitely seems like the right approach. The adjustments you made seems to be working, but the Else: clause isn't taking the information from row A, (although the numbers are being placed in the right place, the words aren't).

I can make a start in fixing this myself, though. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Oh, it worked on the test data you supplied, if you changed the target you may need to adjust some of the numbers, I think. I'm sure someone has a better way to use the array, but I ended up constantly resizing it and it just wasn't effective, so I went back to 1 dimension and printing it

Comment: Great. Once you get the array working, I'd say it would be fine to post that code as a question, as I'm sure my variant method is *not* optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Looping through anything is slower than bulk operations but if you have to loop, loop through a variant array not the worksheet; even if you have to do it twice.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrepLibrary()
    Dim iDigits As Long, iAlphas As Long
    Dim a As Long, v As Long, vVALs As Variant, vLIBs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Library")
        'no need to redim - loading the values builds the array
        vVALs = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    'everything is in the first variant array; define the scope of the results
    For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
        If IsNumeric(vVALs(v, 1)) Then
            iDigits = iDigits + 1
            a = 1
        Else
            a = a + 1
            iAlphas = IIf(a > iAlphas, a, iAlphas)
        End If
    Next v

    'redim the results array to receive the values based on the scope determined immediately above
    ReDim vLIBs(1 To iAlphas, 1 To iDigits)
    'you can get rid of the next two lines when you are confident of your methods
    Debug.Print LBound(vLIBs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vLIBs, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(vLIBs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vLIBs, 2)

    'populate the results array
    iDigits = 0: iAlphas = 0
    For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
        If IsNumeric(vVALs(v, 1)) Then
            iDigits = iDigits + 1
            iAlphas = 1
            vLIBs(iAlphas, iDigits) = vVALs(v, 1)
        Else
            iAlphas = iAlphas + 1
            vLIBs(iAlphas, iDigits) = vVALs(v, 1)
        End If
    Next v

    'drop the results back to the workbook
    'I will put them back in the same worksheet radiating out from C1
    With Worksheets("Library")
        'the target cells have to be the same size and shape as the variant array
        .Cells(1, 3).Resize(UBound(vLIBs, 1), UBound(vLIBs, 2)) = vLIBs
    End With

    'usually not necessary but I like peace-of-mind
    Erase vVALs: Erase vLIBs
End Sub
```

I didn't build 20K rows of test data this time around but judging from similar past experiences this shouldn't take longer than a second or two for 20K values.